# PHP script automatically convert content in open data formats

Tags: data-format, programming

Is there a PHP script that can take posts from my website and convert them to CSV, RDF, etc.? Can someone help?

Comment: You should include more details. What is the structure of your posts? Do you need any special information (like: tags, date, users, likes etc) or just the content? It is difficult to find a script that works from everyone. Probably you should create it by yourself or give details here to let someone help you. Also, what is your database? Most of them have somekind of extractors to csv.

Comment: i have a mysql database and a wordpress website.
i want to export categories (and content) to open data formats. 
i'm not good at programming and i'm asking if there is something that can be used as "starting point".

Comment: can you define open data formats more? i see csv, and rdf....your blog has an rss feed, no?

Comment: another random thought...if you implement microformats in your markup, along with the correct markup for syndicated content, you should be setting yourself up for success...i know you still need the script(s)...care to share your url?

Answer (score 3):

I found this Wordpress Plugin [WP-CSV](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-csv/)

Details:

- More than 50000 lines can be imported/exported (the only limit is
  your server)
- Posts, pages, and custom post types
- Tags, categories,   and custom taxonomies
- Custom fields (simple and complex)
- Thumbnails
- Flexible filter system to easily control which fields export
- Simple User Interface (if you know Excel or another spreadsheet
  program, you will find this plugin quite easy) The plugin should now
  be usable with most plugins that are fully WordPress compliant.